# Splitting a CSV list from a xkeyval key argument into parts

Tags: macros, indexing, package-writing, etoolbox, xkeyval

Is it possible to store the key value argument (a cvs list) to a macro (via `\def`) and split/further process the content of that macro with `\forcsvlist` command from `etoolbox` package?

I want to provide a list of index entries, separated by `,` such that each entry can be formatted and layout in a special way (as index/glossary, details will still have to be defined).

It is possible (see MWE) to use the `\index` command directly in the body definition of the `\define@key` - command within a a `\forcvslist` statement, leading to some kind of `\immediate\write` to the index file.

I rather want to process the entries of the cvs list later on, say, in a special command called `\MyCmd`, saying `\forcvslist{\index}{\KVMacroCSVList}`, where the `\index` command may be wrapped by another one expecting the list splitting input as last argument.

However, even the simplified form with `\index` as argument to `\forcsvlist`  fails with the error message

> ! Undefined control sequence.  \string \indexentry
>   {\KVMacroCSVList 
>                                                   }{\thepage } l.47 \MyCmd[IndexList={First,Second}]

Here is my non-working MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter

\def\KeyFamilyName{SplitListFamily}

\define@key{\KeyFamilyName}{IndexList}[]{%
%Fails to recognize the comma input, does not split!!!
\def\KVMacroIndexList{#1}%
% Generating the index for testing purposes only
\index{#1}%
}%



\define@key{\KeyFamilyName}{CSVList}[]{%
  \def\KVMacroCSVList{#1}%
  \forcsvlist{\index}{#1}% Works 
}%



\newcommand*{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
\setkeys{\KeyFamilyName}{#1}%

% Assume that \KVMacroCSVList is defined 
% Process and format the List%
% However this fails
\forcsvlist{\index}{\KVMacroCSVList}%
}%

\makeatother

\makeindex%
\begin{document}

\chapter{Einstein's theory of relativity}%

\MyCmd[IndexList={First,Second}]

\MyCmd[CSVList={First,Second}]

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here is an image that shows the behaviour, if one comments `\forcsvlist` in `\MyCmd`. The separate entries stem from the second call to `\MyCmd`, where as the single line originates from the first call to `\MyCmd`.

[image]

Is it an issue of `\expandafter`, `\protected` etc?

**Edit**

I am not sticking to `\forcvslist`, another approach will do also.

Comment: Probably `\@xp\forcsvlist\@xp{\@xp\index\@xp}\@xp{\KVMacroCSVList}` where `\@xp` stands for `\expandafter`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, that works, but how complicated this looks ;-) I suspected that it has to do with `\@xp`, even with a double application of it, but not 5 of it ;-)

Comment: `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\forcsvlist{\noexpand\index}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\KVMacroCSVList}}}\x` is not easier.

Comment: @egreg: No, it does not look easier.  Will you provide an full answer to 'close' this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use

```
\expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter
  {\expandafter\index\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\KVMacroCSVList}
```

Yes, five of them, because you want to expand the list macro before `\forcsvlist` acts upon it.

A different approach with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyCmd}{ O{} }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { hupfer/index } { #1 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_hupfer_index_items_clist
   {
    \hupfer_wrap_index:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \hupfer_wrap_index:n #1
 {
  \index{#1} % for demonstration purposes
 }

\keys_define:nn { hupfer/index }
 {
  IndexList .clist_set:N = \l_hupfer_index_items_clist,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Einstein's theory of relativity}

\MyCmd[IndexList={First,Second}]

\printindex
\end{document}
```